# Given a complex number $c_1$, is there a theorem, or any other way that guarantees that $c_1$ belongs to at least one Julia set?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-dynamics

Let $c_1\in \mathbb{C}$. Let $f_{c_2}(z)=z^2+c_2$ be a quadratic polynomial with $c_2\in\mathbb{C}$, and let be the Julia set defined as 
$$J(f_{c_2})=\{ z\in\mathbb{C}:\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, |f_{c_2}^n(0)|\leq \max(c_2,2)\},$$

where $f_{c_2}^n$ is the $n$th iterate  of $f_{c_2}$. My question is: is there a theorem, or some other way that guarantees that it is always possible to find a $c_2$ such that $c_1\in J(f_{c_2})$? or is it something trivial, since $c_2$ can be any number in the complex plane, and therefore in principle it is always possible to find such parameter that would permit that $c_1\in J(f_{c_2})$?

Comment: I've edited your question to account for the fact that the escape radius is actually $\max(2,c)$, rather than just $2$. Also, what you've really defined here is called the [*filled* Julia set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filled_Julia_set); the Julia set is the boundary of the filled Julia set. If you are really interested in the filled Julia set, then the answer is definitely affirmative, as the filled Julia set for $c=0$ is the unit disk and contains all the numbers that my comment to the answer missed.

Comment: Suppose for a moment I want *only* the points that belong to the boundary of filled Julia set (the Julia set itself, that is), how would that change to know if $c_1$ belongs or not to the boundary of the filled Julia set? (how could it be determined)

Answer (score 1):

For aesthetic reasons (to get rid of subscripts) I will change the notation slightly: The question is whether for any given $w \in \mathbb{C}$ there exists $c \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $w \in J(f_c)$.

If $w=0$, you can use $c=-2$, since $J(f_{-2}) = [-2,2]$ contains $0$. If $|w| > 1/2$, you can define $c = w-w^2$, then $f_c(w) = w^2+c = w$ and $|f'(w)| = |2w| > 1$, so that $w$ is a repelling fixed point of $f_c$, and thus $w \in J(f_c)$.

For $0<|w|\le 1/2$ there is an argument using some slightly more advanced complex dynamics. Let $C$ denote the open main cardioid of the Mandelbrot set. Pick any $c_0 \in \partial C$ for which $f_{c_0}$ has a Cremer point, i.e., a non-linearizable irrationally indifferent fixed point. In particular, $J(f_{c_0})$ has no interior, so either $w \in J(f_{c_0})$, or $w \in A_\infty(f_{c_0})$, where $A_\infty$ denotes the basin of infinity. In the first case we are done, picking $c=c_0$. In the second case, it is easy to see that $w \in A_\infty(f_c)$ for $|c-c_0|$ sufficiently small, since the condition that $|f_c^n(w)| > R$ for some escape radius $R$ is an open condition on $c$, for fixed $n$. This now means that there exists $c_1 \in C$ for which $w \in A_\infty(f_{c_1})$. Also, we know that $w \in K(f_{0})^\circ$ (where the circle denotes interior of the filled-in Julia set.) Let $A$ and $B$ be the sets of those $c \in C$ for which $w$ is in $K(f_c)^\circ$ and $A_\infty(f_c)$, respectively. Both of these are open (for $A$ this requires another argument that the condition of converging to an attracting fixed point is an open condition, which you can find in complex dynamics texts) and non-empty. If $w \notin J(f_c)$ for all $c \in C$, then $C = A \cup B$ would be a partition of $C$ into open, disjoint, non-empty sets, contradicting the fact that $C$ is connected.

I don't know whether there is a more elementary argument for the case $0<|w| \le 1/2$, that would still be an interesting question.